# Is it possible to use html anchors in a long SVG to jump around a very tall SVG?(on the same page)

Tags: html, svg

details: simple html page with an embedded svg

```
    ...
    <body>
    <div id="handlePageWrapper">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="longFile.svg" style='width: 100%;'>
                Your browser does not support SVG
        </object>
    </div>
    </body>
    ...
```

I want to jump around this long single svg like a webpage anchor while staying on the same page. The svg is around 7000px high and 450px wide in a 450px wide browser window.

Does anyone have ideas about how this could be accomplished? is it even possible? I know i can use this to jump to another page but could find nothing on how to jump around one large svg image on the same html page.

I have tried several things including:

```
<a xlink:href="#jumpA" target='_self'>
     <circle fill="#F39800" cx="306.807" cy="803.241" r="33.499"/>
</a>
```

to jump to:

```
<a name='jumpA'>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 58.6738 2291.7451)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Meiryo'" font-size="22.5">
             JUMP HERE PLEASE
      </text>
</a>
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [SVG fragment identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers) to impose a different transform or viewBox on the SVG which would have that effect. E.g.

```
<a xlink:href="#svgView(viewBox(0,200,1000,1000)))">Jump here please</a>
```